# How to pass an array via php to php soap server?

Tags: php, arrays, object, soap, parameters

Sorry, maybe a very easy thing, but I can't get it to work since days!

This is a part of my wsdl:

```
<xsd:complexType name="PERSON"> 
<xsd:sequence> 
    <xsd:element name="ExterneID" minOccurs="0" type="xsd:int" />
    <xsd:element name="Email" type="xsd:string" />
    ...
</xsd:sequence> 
</xsd:complexType>

<message name="insertAdresse">
    <part name="BmLogin" type="xsd:string" />
    <part name="TS" type="xsd:int" />
    <part name="UT" type="xsd:string" />
    <part name="Person" type="typens:PERSON"/>
</message>
```

How can I pass this to my soap server? And how can I address the params there?

I've tried a lot of versions, but nothing helped! Example:

```
class c_adresse
{
    public $ExterneID;
    public $Email;

    public function __construct($ExterneID,$Email)
    {
        $this->ExterneID = $ExterneID;
        $this->Email = $Email;
    }
}

$no1 = array();
$no1[] = new c_adresse(33,"peter@xxxxxx.at");
```

So $no1 looks like:

```
array(1) {
[0]=>
  object(c_adresse)#2 (2) {
    ["ExterneID"]=>
    int(33)
    ["Email"]=>
    string(15) "peter@xxxxxx.at"
  }
}
```

Call:

```
$response = $soap_client->insertAdresse($login,$ts,$token,$no1);
```

The error message:

```
PHP Fatal error:  SOAP-ERROR: Encoding: object hasn't 'Email' property in /home/peter/Desktop/soap.php on line 41
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught SoapFault exception: [Client] SOAP-ERROR: Encoding: object hasn't 'Email' property in /home/peter/Desktop/soap.php:41
```

How to design the object/array(?) to pass to the soap server?

An at the server I can not address $daten. Sometimes, when I play with the order and the style of the parameters, I get it to work somehow and only if I do not mix string, int and arrays (the complexType [PERSON]) in the "message" Section.
But then I can not address $daten or $BmLogin is empty and so on...

```
function insertAdresse($BmLogin,$TS,$UT,$daten)
```

**okay, I've found the solution!**

I changed this:

```
<xsd:element name="PERSON" type="PersonType"/>
<xsd:complexType name="PersonType">
```

then this ...

```
$response = $soap_client->insertAdresse($login,$ts,$token,array("ExterneID"=>22,"Email"=>"peter@xxxxxx.at"));
```

works fine!

Comment: Show the actual SOAP call you're making.

Comment: thanks Jack for your help, I think it's done... (see above) I will do some more checks ...

Comment: post an answer for clarity.

Comment: @Peter - As DoSparKot mentioned, it's good practice to post answers in the answer section (rather than editing your question). Even if you asked the question you're encouraged to post an answer in the normal section.

Comment: yes, sorry - I did some mins ago

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**okay, I've found the solution!**

This was missing in the WSDL:

```
<xsd:element name="PERSON" type="typens:PersonType"/>
<xsd:complexType name="PersonType">
```

then this ...

```
$response = $soap_client->insertAdresse($login,$ts,$token,array("ExterneID"=>22,"Email"=>"peter@xxxxxx.at"));
```

works fine!